# Roman to Integer using JavaScript could not pass all tests

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, roman-numerals

I am trying to solve this problem Roman to integer problem in LeetCode by using JavaScript. The code I got so far did not pass all tests. it is working only in some of the cases.
for example, it passes test for "III" and it returns back 3, but for case where the string is "LVIII", it returns only 57 instead of 58. Also in case where string is "MCMXCIV", it returns back 1990 instead of 1994. It seems that the for loop stopped too early for some reason.
Can someone please have a look at it and please let me know where I got it wrong, thanks.

```js
var romanToInt = function(s) {
    var strArr = s.split('');
    var numArr = [];

    var int = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<strArr.length; i++) {
        if(strArr[i] === 'I'){
            numArr.push(1)
        } else if(strArr[i] === 'V') {
            numArr.push(5)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'X') {
            numArr.push(10)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'L') {
            numArr.push(50)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'C') {
            numArr.push(100)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'D') {
            numArr.push(500)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'M') {
            numArr.push(1000)
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<=numArr.length; i++) {
      if(numArr[0] === 1000) {
        int += 1000;
        numArr.shift();
    } else if(numArr[0] >= numArr[1]) {
        int += (numArr[0] + numArr[1]);
        numArr.splice(0, 2);
    } else if(numArr[0] < numArr[1]){
        int += (numArr[1] - numArr[0]);
        numArr.splice(0, 2);
    } else {
        int += numArr[0]
    }
    }
    

   return int;
};

console.log(romanToInt("III"), "should be 3");
console.log(romanToInt("LVIII"), "should be 58");
console.log(romanToInt("MCMXCIV"), "should be 1994");
```

Comment: I think my logical thinking behind the code is making this problem more complicated than it should be and it is part of the reason the code failed as comparing two elements as a group then removing them is making it harder to suit all situations.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments before. I realised that part of the reason my code did
not work is because the logical thinking behind the coding as it made it too complex.
I will post the updated code someone else provided to me before down below just in case someone out there is looking for solution for this problems. Hope this will help, thanks.

```js
var romanToInt = function(s) {
    var strArr = s.split('');
    var numArr = [];

    var int = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<strArr.length; i++) {
        if(strArr[i] === 'I'){
            numArr.push(1)
        } else if(strArr[i] === 'V') {
            numArr.push(5)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'X') {
            numArr.push(10)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'L') {
            numArr.push(50)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'C') {
            numArr.push(100)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'D') {
            numArr.push(500)
        }else if(strArr[i] === 'M') {
            numArr.push(1000)
        }
    }

 for (var i = 0; i < numArr.length - 1; i++) {
     if(numArr[i] < numArr[i+1]) {
         int -= numArr[i];
     } else {
         int += numArr[i];
     }
    
 }

  int += numArr[numArr.length -1]

    return int;
};
```